# Total probability-DEFECTIVE CARS

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

An industrial conglomerate manufactures a certain type of car in 3 cities: Florence,
Guadalajara and Houston. Of 1,000 cars in Florence, 20% are defective; of 2000 of Guadalajara, 10% are defective; and of 3,000 in Houston, 5% are defective. Let's suppose. You buy a car from a reseller company. We define the event D as obtaining a
defective car, F how to get a car made in Florence, G how to get a car made in Guadalajara and H how to get a car made in Houston.

How could I find the total probability of this

$P(F|H^c)$ and of this $P(D|H^c)$

I have the idea that I could use $P(A) = P$(A $\cap$ B)+$P$(A $\cap$ B$^c$)

(Sorry for my "mathematic code" I'm new in it and for my English too :c)

Sorry I have trouble understanding no matter how much I read in books.

Comment: The probability a car from the 6000 cars you describe came from florence given that it didn't come from houston?  $\Pr(F\mid H^c)$?  Well... let's stop and think about that for a moment... how many cars are there that didn't come from houston?  How many of those came from florence?

Comment: Alternate hint... just use your definition of conditional probability directly.  $\Pr(F\mid H^c) = \dfrac{\Pr(F\cap H^c)}{\Pr(H^c)}$ and recognize that all cars which came from florence couldn't have come from houston.

Comment: As for the other, again use basic definition and recognize $\Pr(D\cap H^c)$ as $\Pr(D\cap F)+\Pr(D\cap G)$ as well as remembering your multiplication rule of probability (*i.e. the exact same basic definition of conditional probability used earlier, just rearranged as a multiplication rather than a division*)

Answer (score 1):

i)$\,\,P(F|H^{c})=\dfrac{P(F\cap(F\cup\,G)}{P(F\cup\,G)}$=

=$\dfrac{P(F)\cup\,P(F\cap\,G)}{P(F)+P(G)}$=$\dfrac{P(F)}{P(F)+P(G)}$

=$\dfrac{1/6}{(1/6)+(2/6)}$=$\dfrac{1}{3}$

ii)$\,\,P(D|H^{c})=\dfrac{P(D\cap\,(F\cup\,G))}{P(F)+P(G)}$

=$\dfrac{P(DF)+P(DG)}{P(F)+P(G)}$=$\dfrac{P(D|F)P(F)+P(D|G)P(G)}{P(F)+P(G)}$

=$\dfrac{0.2(1/6)+0.1(2/6)}{1/2}=\dfrac{4}{30}$.

Sorry for any miscalculations!